# Docker service error: Unable to mount any volume

Tags: linux, rhel, mount, docker

I'm trying to create a `docker service`, but not able to mount any volume along side with it. Neither while creating the service nor while updating it.

```
docker service create --replicas 1  --constraint 'node.hostname==apsrd01339' --name watcher-service-nas --mount src=nas,dst=/mnt/volume,type=volume jspuri/watcher-service:latest
```

The service is created but no container are launched. What am I doing wrong?
I'm using RHEL, docker-ce

I'm facing this issue only when creating the service, not while doing the normal `docker run`

[Update: This works if I remove the --mounts params]

I do get this error:

```
unable to pin image jspuri/watcher-service:latest to digest: name unknown: Repo not found
```

But even I don't do `mount`, I get the same error above,  but both my services/containers get launched. Please guide as to what am I doing wrong